# Check if item exists in object and get item

Tags: python, optimization

I need to check if some `item` exists inside an object(what ever works will be fine : `list`, `set`, `dict`, `collection`...) and get back data from that object.
The best way I found yet is to build a `dict`  with identical `key` and `value`:

```
known={}
for item in list:
    if item in known:
        item = known[item]
    else
        known[item] = item
    foo(item)
```

Another way with `list` (but very slow):

```
known=[]
for item in list:
    if not item in known:
        known.insert(0, item)
    else:
        item = known[known.index(item)]
    foo(item)
```

Last one with set():

```
known = set()
for item in list:
    if item in known:
        item = next(i for i in known if i == item)
    else:
        known.add(item)
    foo(item)
```

Does it looks absurd ? I can't think of a simple way to do that, without ugly hacks, loss of performance and/or memory use.

The reason I'm building these abominations instead of doing :

```
for item in list:
    foo(item)
```

is that `items` inside `list` are large strings, and most of them are the same (in the sens of `a == b`), but not identical, (in the sense of `a is b`). And i need to save memory use. So I would like a unique item inside the main object, and send only a *reference* of that item to `foo()`

How could I do that with a good performance/memory/readability compromise ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't follow.  You understand that in Python, pretty much everything is passed by reference already, right?

Comment: @mxdsp Your code functions correctly, so maybe this is a question for Code Review. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm sorry to admit that I don't understand much. I'm not an english speaker and I never had a chance to learn programming basics. I dont think I meant reference. The behavior I expect is that I need every identical items I found inside `list`, to be fully identical : `(item1 is item2) == True`, not just  `(item1 == item2) == True`

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you're looking for a way to map strings that *compare* equal to a single unique instance. In that case, consider using the `intern` built-in function. `intern` places the string into Python's internal "interned string" map, and returns the unique instance of that string. Just call `intern` on the string whenever you need a unique instance of it.

Demo:

```
>>> s1 = "a"
>>> s2 = "b"
>>> s3 = "ab"
>>> s4 = s1 + s2
>>> id(s3)
4300082912
>>> id(s4)
4300081472
>>> s5 = intern(s3)
>>> id(s5)
4300082912
>>> id(intern(s4))
4300082912
```

Demo 2 (Python 2):

```
>>> arr = [str(x // 2) for x in range(1000, 1010)]
>>> arr
['500', '500', '501', '501', '502', '502', '503', '503', '504', '504']
>>> map(id, arr) # all strings in arr are distinct
[4300081512, 4300081552, 4300081592, 4300081672, 4300081712, 4300081752, 4300081792, 4300081832, 4300081872, 4300081912]
>>> arr2 = map(intern, arr)
>>> arr2
['500', '500', '501', '501', '502', '502', '503', '503', '504', '504']
>>> map(id, arr2) # equal strings are identical now
[4300079632, 4300079632, 4300081592, 4300081592, 4300081712, 4300081712, 4300081792, 4300081792, 4300081872, 4300081872]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a `dict` is good, but you can just use `setdefault`. Demo setup:

```
>>> items = [str(i//2) for i in range(6)]
>>> items
['0', '0', '1', '1', '2', '2']
>>> list(map(id, items))
[55450176, 55450240, 55450208, 55450272, 55450304, 55450336]
```

Using the first object for each value:

```
>>> firsts = map({}.setdefault, items, items)
```

Demo that it works:

```
>>> list(map(id, firsts))
[55450176, 55450176, 55450208, 55450208, 55450304, 55450304]
```

Answer (score 0):

what about using sets:

```
lst = ['huge string1', 'huge string1','huge string1','huge string1', 'huge string2', 'huge string2','huge string2','huge string2']
print(lst)
print(set(lst))
```

Output:

```
['huge string1', 'huge string1', 'huge string1', 'huge string1', 'huge string2', 'huge string2', 'huge string2', 'huge string']
{'huge string1', 'huge string2'}
```